# What does X509::Attribute#value return?

Tags: ruby

The [relevant documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Attribute.html#method-i-value) doesn't have much info about the return value of `OpenSSL::X509::Attribute#value`:

```
value => asn1
```

Which presumably refers to something in the `OpenSSL::ASN1` module, but it's not clear to me what.  Does it return an instance of `OpenSSL::ASN1::ASN1Data`?  An array of them?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an instance of `OpenSSL::ASN1::ASN1Data`.

In docs generated by RDoc you can click on a method's calling sequence to view its source code. For `OpenSSL::X509::Attribute#value` it's written in C and contains the following line:

```
return rb_funcall(mASN1, rb_intern("decode"), 1, str);
```

Which is basically equivalent to this Ruby code:

```
mASN1 = OpenSSL::ASN1 # m → module, c would be class, and e → exception
mASN1.send(:decode, str)
```

So the answer to your question can ultimately be found by looking at the [OpenSSL::ASN1.decode](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/ASN1.html#method-c-decode]) doc:

> **OpenSSL::ASN1.decode(der) → ASN1Data**
>
> Decodes a BER- or DER-encoded value and creates an
>   [ASN1Data](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/ASN1/ASN1Data.html)
>   instance.